# ASP NET CORE 2 Deploy

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

i have a issue when i'm trying to deploy an asp net core 2 application. Something strange it's happening and i have no idea what. I get 404 not found on every request that's supposed to be OK. If i throw on exception it works and the endpoint is found, else 404. I never throw a 404 ex from my application.
Any ideas ?
I tried to send an email when it's OK, but my controller is not hit.
I thought that is a FE issue but i tried with Postman.
I think something weird is happening on middle ware but i cannot figure it out.
I checked IIS and all seems to be OK.

Did anyone have this problem before? 
This is happening only on the deployed server, local i don't have any problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any logs from IIS?

Comment: Where are you deploying, locally to IIS? Or to a VM in cloud? Do you have ASCM installed?

Comment: have you tried a raw middleware returning OK?

Comment: See if all dlls have been copied or not!! And where are you deploying by the way?

Comment: If you are using this on an IIS server, try an add "stdoutLogEnabled="true" to the <aspNetCore> configuration in web.config. That will create a log file and show you everything that is happening when the app is running.